# Observable 'of' not exist after update rxjs5 > 6 in Angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

I have updated my app from Angular 5 to Angular 6, and also I had to update rxjs from 5 to 6. I used this [LINK](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs-tslint).

In my code I have: `Observable.of(years)` and I've changed imports from this: `import "rxjs/add/observable/of";` to this:  `import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";` and still `of` cannot be found.

I have an error: `Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'`

Comment: Replace `Observable.of(years)` with `of(years)` See also https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#observable-classes

Comment: it should be `import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';`

Comment: @yurzui Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Import this line in your component

```
  import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

Refer this link for rxjs 6 Changes

> https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/